# Скрипт парсинга видео из источника и публикации этих видео в YouYube

Tags: python, python-2.x, ffmpeg, youtube-api, youtube-dl

Всем привет! Есть следующий скрипт, предназначенный для парсинга видео ТикТок из источника https://www.reddit.com/r/TikTokCringe/hot.json?limit=12 и публикации их на своем youtube-канале:

```
#!/bin/bash

youtube-dl $(curl -s -H "User-agent: 'your bot 0.1'" https://www.reddit.com/r/TikTokCringe/hot.json?limit=12 | jq '.' | grep url_overridden_by_dest | grep -Eoh "https:\/\/v\.redd\.it\/\w{13}") 

for f in *.mp4;
do
  ffmpeg -i $f -lavfi '[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16' -vb 800K blur/$f ;
done

rm *.mp4
for f in blur/*.mp4; do echo "file $f" >> file_list.txt ; done 
ffmpeg -f concat -i file_list.txt final.mp4 
rm -rf blur

python2 $HOME/bw/.local/bin/upload.py --file="final.mp4" --title="Funny TikTok Compilation" --description="Buy my merchandise - spamlink.ly" --keywords="tiktok,cringe" --category="22" --privacyStatus="public"
```

Прошу прояснить следующие моменты:

1. Где именно в скрипте нужно указывать данные своего youtube-канала?
2. Возможно ли в данном скрипте вместо python2 использовать python3?
   Если да, то как это правильно сделать в рамках данного скрипта?
3. Стоит ли вместо youtube-dl использовать yt-dlp? Если да, то как это
   правильно сделать в рамках данного скрипта?
4. И, в целом, что происходит на каждом шаге скрипта и что значат
   указанные опции в каждой из команд.

Comment: 2 - да, возможно, если адаптировать не выложенный вами upload.py, чтобы он работал на python 3.

Comment: 1 - скорее всего в том самом upload.py

Comment: @insolor "если адаптировать не выложенный вами upload.py" - к сожалению, не совсем в этом разбираюсь. Насколько это сложно? Что проще - адаптировать его или в целом искать/создавать новый скрипт?

Comment: Не известно, нужно код смотреть.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за уточнения!

Answer (score 1):

вызывается в последней команде скрипта. Конкретнее, в параметрах --title, --description, --keywords и --category нужно указать свои данные.

Да, можно использовать Python 3 вместо Python 2.

Стоит использовать yt-dlp вместо youtube-dl, так как он является более современным и поддерживает большее количество функций и сайтов. Для использования yt-dlp в данном скрипте нужно заменить youtube-dl на yt-dlp.

В целом, скрипт делает следующее:

Получает JSON с популярными видео на Reddit из подраздела TikTokCringe и извлекает ссылки на видео в формате v.redd.it.
Скачивает видео с помощью youtube-dl (или yt-dlp).
Применяет эффект размытия к каждому видео с помощью ffmpeg.
Объединяет все видео в один файл.
Загружает видео на YouTube с помощью upload.py.

Comment: Привет! Спасибо за ответ! Был найден только сам скрипт, а вот файла upload.py к нему не было. Если я правильно понял, то это файл, в котором и указывается API-данные своего youtube-канала. Как создать (написать) этот файл?